# JS insertAdjacentHTML() is completely ignored

Tags: javascript

Breaking my head to understand why is `insertAdjasentHTML` has no effect on DOM:

```
console.log(target);
console.log(`${this.errorTemplate.replace('ERROR_MESSAGE', e.message)}`);
target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `${this.errorTemplate.replace('ERROR_MESSAGE', e.message)}`);
```

Here's the console output:

```
<input class="form-control input-round is-invalid" type="text" name="login_form[email]" id="login_form_email">

<div class="invalid-feedback d-block">Please enter a valid email address</div>
```

So, just nothing happens. Nothing is inserted.

Comment: Please elaborate more, the question isn't very clear

Comment: @Rilla fixed the question. Is this clearer now?

Comment: show your errorTemplate value and target value

Comment: @EugenSunic they're already in the question. Second snippet.

Comment: show your target definition how do you fetch it from the DOM, more code is needed for target and errorTemplate

Comment: It should work. I can't figure out it isn't working

Comment: If ${this.errorTemplate.replace('ERROR_MESSAGE', e.message)} returns a dom element it wouldn't work

Comment: The second parameter of insertAdjacentHTML should be a dom string eg: '<div>Hello world</div>'

Comment: @Rilla it cannot return a dom element, replace always returns a string.

Comment: Okay for testing purposes try using any dummy dom string as second parameter of insertAdjacentHTML... Eg: target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<h1>Testing</h1>')

Answer (score 1):

My bad. Everything worked perfectly. It's just that the upper function was ran on a batch of targets, and each time it destroyed all the previous insertions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you errorTemplate is of type string not object, otherwise you'll get an error stating replace method does not exist on the object etc.

When inserting the adjacent it needs to be a string, so if you have a DOM element such as a paragraph which needs to be inserted as an adjacent then define it as a string completely.

The replace method is irrelevant here it just returns a new string hence ignore it for resolving your root issue.

Here is an example (assuming the target is the invalid email address node element):

```js
const target = document.querySelector('.invalid-feedback')
// should be a string
const errorTemplate = '<p>ERROR_MESSAGE</p>';
target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', errorTemplate.replace('ERROR_MESSAGE', 'NEW ERROR MESSAGE'));
```

```html
<input class="form-control input-round is-invalid" type="text" name="login_form[email]" id="login_form_email">
<div class="invalid-feedback d-block">Please enter a valid email address</div>
```

Likewise, please go through the official docs for more clarification:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML